# What is the difference between an array and a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-allocation

What is the difference between the following two types of array?

```
int array1[10];
int* array2 = new int[10];
```

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that a dynamic array is created on the heap.  A dynamic array's size can be determined at runtime.

The difference in the below:

```
int x = 10;
int array1[10];
int *array2 = new char[x];
```

Is that `array2` is pointing to the first element of an array and not the actual full array.

Note:

```
assert(sizeof(array1) == 40);
assert(sizeof(array2) == 4);
```

Memory on the heap that is created with new should eventually be destroyed using `delete`.
Since `array2` is created on the heap, and is an array you will need to delete it with `delete[]` though.

Note: You can actually create a pointer to a full array and not just the first element:

```
int array1[10];
int *pointerToFirstElement = array1;
int (*pointerToFullArray)[10] = &array1;
int sizeOfFirstPointer = sizeof(pointerToFirstElement);
int sizeOfSecondPointer = sizeof(pointerToFullArray);
assert(sizeOfFirstPointer == sizeOfSecondPointer);//==4 since both are pointers
```

However what they point to have different sizes:

```
int sizeOfFirst = sizeof(*pointerToFirstElement);
int sizeOfSecond = sizeof(*pointerToFullArray);
assert(*sizeOfFirst == 4);
assert(*sizeOfSecond == 40);
```

Comment: *"It's size can be determined at compile time."* - should that have been *"can't"* or refer to non-dynamic arrays?

Comment: By the way I always thought `int (*pointerToFullArray)[10] = new int[10];`
 should be allowed and required in C++.

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic array is created from heap memory at run time and can be dynamically resized/freed as necessary with the new/delete keywords. An array is statically defined at compile time and will -always- take that amount of memory at all times.